# Execute multiple queries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, view

I'm trying to join two views which I create in a query.
The query works fine in MySQL but when I execute it with PHP it looks like it's not actually executing because I can't visualize the two views in the db.

The query I'm executing is the following:

```php
$query1 = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW new_tbl AS SELECT
AnagTav.Id,
AnagTav.Riga,
AnagTav.Colonna,
AnagTav.Costo,
AnagTav.Nome,
AnagTav.NumeroPersone,
PrenPic.Data AS Occupato,
PrenPic.IdUtente
FROM `AnagraficaTavoli` AS AnagTav
LEFT JOIN PrenotazioniPicNic AS PrenPic ON PrenPic.IdTavolo = AnagTav.Id
WHERE (PrenPic.Data >= '".$dateFrom."' AND PrenPic.Data <= '".$dateTo."')
OR PrenPic.Data IS NULL
GROUP BY CASE
WHEN AnagTav.Nome != '' THEN AnagTav.Nome
ELSE AnagTav.Id
END
ORDER BY AnagTav.Riga ASC, AnagTav.Colonna;
                            
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW new_tbl2 AS SELECT 
AnagraficaTavoli.*,
Occupato,
IdUtente
FROM AnagraficaTavoli
LEFT JOIN new_tbl ON (AnagraficaTavoli.Id = new_tbl.Id)
WHERE new_tbl.Id IS NULL;";
$result=$conn->query($query1);
```

After creating the 2 views I execute a second query:

```
if($result){
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM new_tbl
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM new_tbl2
    ORDER BY Riga ASC, Colonna;";
    $resultList=$conn->query($query2); 
    while($rowList=$resultList->fetch_assoc())
    {
        //I do stuff here
    }
}
```

`$conn` is my connection to the db

I tried printing the query and executing it on MySQL, but it works fine.
I don't know why I'm getting this error and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: error is telling you correctly, you are trying to execute fetch_assoc method in a boolean value. Also once you get proper object out there, you will get an error of that "fetch_assoc" method does also not exist. Please read manual with more carefulness.

Comment: @yergo what do you mean with ""fetch_assoc" method does also not exist"?
I have used it many times and it works just fine with a single query

Comment: Also @yergo I knew the error was I was getting a boolean as result but I wanted to know why.
Because if I change the query with a single select it works fine :)

Comment: Ok my fault at fetch_assoc, it is mysqli not pdo. If you drive into examples of using 'query' methid, you willnotice their are always inside 'if' statement. This is because you when 'query' method fails with an error, it responds with 'false' which I assume is your "boolean value"

Comment: first of all try executing the query which create the temporary table separately, and once the two temporary table are created successfully, execute the select query separately and then call fetch_assoc() on it

Comment: What altogether basically leads to a conclusion, that your query is executing with errors.

Comment: @Ashishrawat I would love if that was possible... sadly these are temporary tables and will not exist on the execution of a second query :/ (I guess, maybe I'm wrong but mySql documentation says that)

Comment: @yergo Ok so i guess you are telling me that my query fails... the problem is that if I take the query and paste it in mySql it works and gives the correct result.
The problem I think is that php can't handle 3 querys in 1 and gives an error on the second one (I tryed using ```mysql_query($query)``` and it breaks on creation of the second temp table).
Is there a way I can execute this query and not get an error?

Comment: did you tried doing it using creating view .

Comment: @Ashishrawat to be honest I did't and I don't even know how to do that.
Could you post an answer helping me with that?

Comment: You should read more about getting errors back from mysql, it is possible to fetch error messages after failed execution (once you have false in $resultList it is a failed execution). I would separate querie to three different calls - if ypu wont disconnect inbetween, temporary tables will remain.

Comment: @yergo oh ok I didn't know that.
I'll try and let you know if that worked!
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: kindly check the answer, may be it can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be non obvious, but if you keep your script connected, you can access you temporary tables in separate queries. What you should do is to slice your query into three different operations, especially the "select" being a separate one. Only having single select statement in a query, php will be able to properly fetch resultset.

Comment: I am selecting this as correct answer because the only way it works is separating ALL of the querys and not only the select.
Consider updating specifying that.
Thanks for the help

Comment: I will test it out. I am pretty sure, that it is a matter of 'select', yet it might differ between pdo/mysqli and if so, should be pointed out.